# How to add CSS to CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

CKEDITOR is using to add news on site.

I want to add classes in parts of text texteditor and view this text like they would be on site.

I have wrote this.

In plugins/styles/styles/default.js

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add(
'default',
[
    {
        name:'style',
        element:'span',
        attributes: { 'class': 'test' }
    }
    ]);
```

config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  config.contentsCss = '/tpl/index/css/main.css';
  config.bodyClass = 'test';
}
```

main.css

```
test {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

So i want to highlight the text and set class='test' to this text.
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want

```
.test {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I want to set some class to highlight text. For example 'test' and have text 30px in editor.

Comment: The content of your main.css defines a rule for an element with a tag of "test", so I'm suggesting you to fix it so it's really for elements with class "test"

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the dot. Thank you.